# container div height does not scale to match height of child SVG in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg

I have a container div that has a SVG inside of it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="50" height="200">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="200" />
    </svg>
    </div>
</body>
```

And the following CSS:

```
svg
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
div.container
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

In firefox, chrome etc. the container div will match the height of the svg. However this isn't the case for IE (I tested it in IE9). Removing the width/height: 100% from the svg style block will fix this, however I need these styles in order to scale my SVG (I've left out preserveAspectRatio in the SVG element in this example jsfiddle).

Here is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Cx5jR/

I was thinking that I could use zoom:1 to force IE to recognize hasLayout on the div element, but this didn't work.

Any ideas?

Here's a screenshot from how the rendering looks in IE9 - notice that the div (red background) doesn't scale beneath the SVG (black rectangle) height.

[image: IE9 bug svg scale bg]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the problem?  I'm not sure I'm seeing the same issue in IE9 as you - though the rendering isn't the same as in Chrome.  Also, why not set `height:200px` if you know the height of the .SVG in advance?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the SVG i set in this example is just a dummy - in my real example I don't know what height nor width the SVG will be until after page load. I use offsetWidth to get the width (responsive layout) and then calculate height from that.

Comment: In that case, a screenshot of the behavior would still be helpful (I want to make sure I'm replicating the issue).

Comment: Yes, just added it to my post!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SVG currently lacks a `viewBox` attribute, which is needed for consistent cross-browser rendering.  The lack of `viewBox`, combined with setting the `width` and `height` of the SVG to 100% in the CSS seems to be the root of the problem.

Here is a jsfiddle that has consistent rendering across Chrome and IE9: http://jsfiddle.net/Cx5jR/3/.

The following is added to the `<svg>` tag:
`viewBox="0 0 50 200"`
(starting X coordinate, starting Y, ending X, ending Y)

And `height` and `width` in the CSS for the `<svg>` are removed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I will try this later tonight - and let you know.

Comment: After adding the viewBox i noticed that I didnt need the height on SVG set to 100% in order for the SVG to scale accordingly to my responsive layout. If I used 100% height the same issue happened even though I had the viewBox. However adding viewBox and preserveAspectRatio seems to have fixed my issues in IE9. Thanks!